# HibernateListener-Class not found error

Tags: java, hibernate, struts, hql, sessionfactory

I am trying to create hibernate listener.I was created listener by help of this article.http://www.developer.am/documentation/struts2/?page=struts-2-hibernate-integration-example
In web.xml i configured listener..I am getting following error.How can i fix this issue??

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class  
    com.it.utils.HibernateListener
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
at com.it.utils.HibernateListener.contextInitialized(HibernateListener.java:31)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at         

   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
at 
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at 
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
... 11 more
```

I will share web.xml..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  

  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>WelcomeStruts</display-name>
   <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>

     <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>register.jsp</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>
     <listener>
    <listener-class>
 com.itac.utils.HibernateListener
     </listener-class>
       </listener>
```

```
   I am using following jar files in buildpath

        x-wrapper-comp-1.8.0.jar
antlr.jar
antlr-2.7.6rc1.jar
antlr-4.0-complete.jar
apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
asm.jar
asm-attrs.jar
c3p0-0.9.2-pre1.jar
cglib-2.1.3.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar
commons-fileupload.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-lang-2.3.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
commons-validator.jar
datafile.jar
displaytag-1.2.jar
displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.15.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
gson-2.2.2.jar
hibernate.cfg.xml
hibernate3.jar
httpclient-4.0.1.jar
httpcore-4.0.1.jar
httpmime-4.0.1.jar
iText-2.1.7.jar
jaas.jar
jackson-all-1.9.4.jar
jakarta-oro.jar
jasperreports-3.7.4.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
jaxen-1.1-beta-7.jar
jaxrpc.jar
jcommon-1.0.16.jar
jdbc2_0-stdext.jar
jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
jsfcompounds-0.0.2.jar
json-lib-2.1.jar
jstl.jar
jta.jar
log4j-1.2.11.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar
mchange-commons-0.2.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
notifier.jar
ognl-2.7.3.jar
ognl-3.0.5.jar
org.json-0.0.1.jar
poi-3.5-beta5-20090219.jar
saaj.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar
standard.jar
struts.xml
struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar
struts2-core-2.3.7.jar
struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
struts2-portlet-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
struts2-tiles-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
tiles-api-2.0.6.jar
tiles-core-2.0.6.jar
tiles-jsp-2.0.6.jar
util-bridges.jar
util-java.jar
util-taglib.jar
vssver2.scc
webservices-api.jar
webservices-extra.jar
webservices-extra-api.jar
webservices-rt.jar
webservices-tools.jar
wsdl4j.jar
xwork-core-2.1.6.jar
xwork-core-2.3.7.jar
```

Comment: did you add dom4j as maven dependency? Do you use maven? If not just download dom4j http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/ and put jar to classpath

Comment: i am not using maven dependency..also i added that jar to class path.still showing issue

Comment: Error is happening in this line,  config = new Configuration().configure(url);

Comment: The problem is that your jar still unavailable for tomcat. Hibernate uses XMLHelper class inside configure method, https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.java, Xmlhelper uses Jdom https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/util/xml/XMLHelper.java

Comment: put this dom4j jar at tomcat lib directory

Comment: Now that error is gone..now it is swoing another error...

Comment: Now it is showing another Error:Error configuring application listener of class com.it.utils.HibernateListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.it.utils.HibernateListener atorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass( WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)

Comment: check your listener defenition at web.xml

Comment: in web.xml,i configured like this..  <listener-class>
  com.it.utils.HibernateListener
    </listener-class>

Comment: check either your HibernateListener class is available for tomcat or not. How you deploy you application? Show your web.xml

Comment: update question..above i added web.xml

Comment: show me your jar-files, your application is unable to find the concern jar file at run-time, as well as configure() method is also unavailable  to your application.

Comment: @ arvin_codeHunk.updated question..added jar list

Comment: what is you developer environment and which IDE is used?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911